# Cancel process when reached time out with asyncio python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I try to cancel process when timeout but asyncio.wait_for not working. How do i cancel process when reached time out. My code below:

```
import asyncio
async def process():
    # do something take a long time like this
    for i in range(0,10000000000,1):
        for j in range(0,10000000000,1):
            continue
    print('done!')

async def main():
    # I want to cancel process when reached timeout
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(process(), timeout=1.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout!')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because your `process` function is async in name only - it doesn't **await** anything. That means that it finishes in its entirety without giving the event loop a chance to interrupt it. Since asyncio is cooperative (as are other async/await based systems), such a function is not a correctly written async function and cannot be interrupted.

If you add an `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)` into the inner loop (or anything else that awaits something that actually suspends), your code will work fine.